# Trouble viewing questions with a specific tag - hotkeys in my case

Tags: support, questions

I'd like to view all questions tagged with "hotkeys"  but it says something about no questions with an active bounty.

Comment: Click on the Newest or Active tab

Answer (score 4):

When you see the following:

> You are on the Featured tab.
>
> There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.
>
> Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

Click on either Newest or Active sort to view questions in the selected tag that aren't restricted by open bounties.